# association and migration between users and teams (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-migrations

I have this User and team model which has the following association:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
```

team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_one :leader, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "leader_id"
    belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "manager_id"
```

but it seems that I can't imagine representing it properly into a migration. At first, this is what I did:

```
class AddTeamIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :users, :team_id, :integer
        add_index :users, :team_id
    end
end

class AddUsersToTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_reference :teams, :leader, index: true
        add_reference :teams, :manager, index: true     
    end
end
```

for sure, what I did on `AddTeamToIdUsers` was a many-to-one association since a `Team` can have many `Users`, but the **leader position** should only be **exclusive for a specific team** only (same goes to members as well, they should not belong to other teams). **Managers**, however, can **have many teams** to manage. Going back to my concern, how can I represent my scenario into a migration? Or are there any adjustments I should make in my associations? After the necessary adjustments and solutions considered, will the application automatically follow the association rules upon adding/updating teams?

Comment: If a user manages a team, are they said to be "part of" that team, ie would they be included in `team.users`?  What about leaders?

Comment: yes for both of your answers. both leader and manager are values for the attribute _type_ for users (default is worker).

Comment: Could a leader or worker also be a manager of a team, ie can a user have multiple types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a manager can have multiple teams, but is still "part of" the team, I'd suggest creating a join table for `users` and `teams`. We'll call it `members`. It will reference both `user` and `team`.

```
class CreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :members do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :team

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then, we'll need add the `members` association to the `User` model. Users will have many members, and, because of managers, have many teams as well. I've also included a function to get the team of a worker or leader, since there's only one.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :teams, through: members, dependent: destroy

  validates_associated :members # More on this later

  # for workers and leaders
  def team
    self.teams.first
  end
end
```

Similar to the `User` model, we'll need to add the `members` association to the `Team` model. We'll also include a few functions to get the leader and manager of a team, and validation to make sure a team has exactly one leader and one manager.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members, dependent: destroy

  validate :has_one_leader_and_manager
  validates_associated :members # More on this later

  def manager
    self.users.where(type: 'manager').first
  end

  def leader
    self.users.where(type: 'leader').first
  end

  def has_one_leader_and_manager
    ['leader', 'manager'].each do |type|
      unless self.users.where(type: type).count == 1
        errors.add(:users, "need to have exactly one #{type}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Lastly, we'll set up the `Member` model. We can also include some validation to ensure that a team can only have one leader and one manager, and that workers and leader cannot belong to more than one team.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team

  validate :team_has_one_leader_and_manager

  # Make sure player (worker or leader) is only on one team
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: true, if: :is_player?

  def is_player?
    ['worker', 'leader'].include? user.type
  end

  def team_has_one_leader_and_manager
    if ['leader', 'manager'].include?(user.type)
      if team.users.where('type = ? AND id != ?' user.type, user_id).count.any?
        errors.add(:team, "can't add another #{user.type}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that with the validation methods, you may want to move them around and/or refactor them, depending on how you add users and team, and how you'll add new members. However, this answer will hopefully give you enough information to get started.

Comment: will my `team_id` foreign key from the users table still be necessary since you added a Members model?

Comment: Oh great point. You won't need `team_id` in your `users` table.

Comment: btw, for my form page, it should have a dropdown list for manager, and leader, so that it will be easy to identify.. for the dropdown list for members, i will try the select2.. so, how will i isolate the selections for manager and leader?

Comment: You can use something along the lines of `User.where(type: 'manager')` as the list for possible managers. You can use something similar for leaders.

Comment: ok, but what will be the content for `team_params` from `Team.new(team_params)` before saving? only `members` (since the leader and manager are part of the `members`)?

Comment: If the same person can have a different role in different teams then you'd need to move the type field into Member.

Comment: You should only have to pass `members`, yes. But it definitely depends on the way your form is laid out.

Comment: btw, your validation doesn't seem to work for me, i got false errors as a result..

Comment: What do you mean by "got false errors as a result"? What were the errors? Was the expected behavior different from the behavior you're observing?

Comment: nevermind, i already solved it on my own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582884/validation-error-through-factorygirl

Answer (score 3):

Your migrations look correct, but your associations are not complete:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_one :leading_team, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: 'leader_id'
  has_many :managed_teams, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key, 'manager_id'

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :leader, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User"
```

And you should be all set.