# Creating Family of Users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I'm trying to group users in families. A family can have one parent and multiple members 
so a parent is considered a member as well.

I have tried answers provided here 
[association and migration between users and teams (rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289861/association-and-migration-between-users-and-teams-rails/24292047)
and here 
[rails many to many self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396831/rails-many-to-many-self-join)
to try to make it work but no luck

Here is what I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# this defines the parent to members fine and you can get them
# only if you have the parent
  has_many :memberships, :class_name => 'Family', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :family_members, :through => :memberships, :source => :registrar
# trying to define that user is also a member of family 
 belongs_to :registrar_family, :foreign_key => 'member_user_id'
end

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :users, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "id"
end
```

So if I have user 1 who is a parent and has four members I can use

```
user.family_members # to get family members for this parent
```

but how do I make so that I can also get the full family from a members

examples of DB

```
Users:
  id, name
 1, King
 2, Queen
 3, Prince
 4, Duaghter 
Users Family: 
 id,user_id, member_user_id
 1, 1, 2
 1, 1, 3 
 1, 1, 4
```

How do I say something like

```
user = User.find(4)
user.family.parent.members # which would return a family association
```

The complete solution for this is (if anyone is interested):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def family
    members = Family.where("user_id = ? OR member_user_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
    # if members is only 1 person then this person is a member only
    # then get all members from parent
    if members.count == 1
      members = members.first.parent.family
    end
    members
  end

  def family_count
    # if there is family then count is family + parent else 0
    family.count > 0 ? family.count + 1 : 0
  end

end

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "user_id"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have reasons you haven't mentioned why you need a `Family` class. But for a simple implementation you can do it all within the `User` model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def is_parent?
    parent_id.nil?
  end

  def family
    User.where(id: id_of_parent).or(User.where(parent_id: id_of_parent))
  end

  private
  def id_of_parent
    is_parent? ? id : parent_id
  end
end
```

if the users table contains

```
| id | first_name | parent_id |
| 1  | Fred       |  nil      |
| 2  | Wilma      |  1        |
| 3  | Pebbles    |  1        |
| 4  | Barney     |  1        |
```

Then:

```rb
> User.find(1).family.map(&:first_name) # -> [Fred,Wilma,Pebbles,Barney]
> User.find(2).family.map(&:first_name) # -> [Fred,Wilma,Pebbles,Barney]
```

You can add a self-join in the User model, if you like, but it doesn't add much:

```rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :parent_id

  etc...
```

I realize it's not *exactly* what you asked, but does it meet your needs?

Comment: The reason I need the family class is that user should be able to confirm and reject that they are part of that family and we need to store that state. I ended up using your approach but a little bit modified :)